How to type partial application?
How to type partial application (preferably with 3.12 syntax)? With the following simple implementation:
class simple_partial:
    def __init__(self, f: Callable, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.f = f
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.f(*(*self.args, *args), **(self.kwargs | kwargs))


partially = simple_partial(lambda x, y, z=3: (x, y, z), 1)
partially(2)

The only thing I can think of is something like:
class simple_partial[T, **P]:
    def __init__(self, f: Callable[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> None:
        self.f = f
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        return self.f(*(*self.args, *args), **(self.kwargs | kwargs))

but this isn't correct because it doesn't express that args/kwargs are potentially incomplete and really P.args and P.kwargs will be different in __init__ and __call__. Maybe this can be done with typing.Concatenate and two ParamSpecs but Concatenate doesn't allow two ParamSpecs.
Edit: Two ParamSpec version:
class simple_partial[T, **P, **P2]:
    def __init__(
        self, f: Callable[Concatenate[P, P2], T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs
    ) -> None:
        self.f = f
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, *args: P2.args, **kwargs: P2.kwargs) -> T:
        return self.f(*(*self.args, *args), **(self.kwargs | kwargs))

Concatenate does not allow two ParamSpecs though.

There's functools.partial(), which might be special cased by type checkers. Does that work for you or am I missing something?

Thank you, that is very interesting! I am not trying to solve a particular problem, just playing with type hints, so that works for me! :)

It’s really not currently (3.12) possible to type simple_partial class regarding his arguments bt we can provide type information for return value
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, Any

T = TypeVar('T')

class simple_partial:
    def __init__(self, f: Callable[..., T], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        self.f= f
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any)-> T:
        return self.f(*self.args, *args, **self.kwargs, **kwargs)

